# Can not find Canvas variables in API Level 28

Tags: android, canvas, android-9.0-pie

The following `Canvas` Variables are not found in Android 28.

```
canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null,
                Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG |
                        Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG |
                        Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                        Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                        Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 28):

Those flags have been removed in API 28. See [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/28/changes/android.graphics.Canvas):

> Class android.graphics.Canvas
>
> Removed Methods
> int save(int)
>
> Removed Fields
> int CLIP_SAVE_FLAG
> int CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
> int FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
> int HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
> int MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG

That method was deprecated in API 26. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#saveLayer(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint,%20int)):

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.
> Use saveLayer(float, float, float, float, Paint) instead.

**What to use instead**

According to the `Canvas` source code for API 28, the flags you use all combine to be equal to the value of `ALL_SAVE_FLAG`:

```
public  static  final  int ALL_SAVE_FLAG =  0x1F;
public  static  final  int MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG =  0x01;
public  static  final  int CLIP_SAVE_FLAG =  0x02;
public  static  final  int HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG =  0x04;
public  static  final  int FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG =  0x08;
public  static  final  int CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG =  0x10;
```

From the same [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r8/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java#513) the call to  `Canvas#saveLayer(left, top, right, bottom, paint)` defaults to using `ALL_SAVE_FLAG`:

```
/**  
 * Convenience for {@link #saveLayer(RectF, Paint)} that takes the four float coordinates of the  
 * bounds rectangle. */
public int saveLayer(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, @Nullable Paint paint) {  
    return saveLayer(left, top, right, bottom, paint, ALL_SAVE_FLAG);  
}
```

So, it looks like your code is equivalent to the following code which you can use as a replacement:

```
canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

This version of *saveLayer()* is only available on API 21+. To support lower API levels, use

```
canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
```

Where `Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG` is the same as the *or'ed* values above.

Comment: I don't understand. What should be used exactly instead of `canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG)` ? Is it `canvas.saveLayer(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),null);` ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes. I added a link to the referenced source code in the answer.

Comment: @Cheticamp Oh ok. Thank you.

Comment: @Cheticamp I am using above but I also get: "Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.graphics.Canvas#saveLayer". What should I do if I want to support API 19 and above?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `canvas.save();` instead of `canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG|CLIP_SAVE_FLAG)`
reference