# error: cannot find symbol variable CLIP_SAVE_FLAG when targeting Android API 28

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I recently switched my targeted platform api from 26 to 28 and now I can't compile my project.

I get this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable CLIP_SAVE_FLAG
```

when I use canvas.save() in my onDraw() method:

```
canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
```

^complains about setting the properties above.

I have nearly the same issue logged here: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/921

How can I resolve this issue so that I can target the latest android apis.

Thanks!

EDIT: I checked the duplicate link here:

[Can not find Canvas variables in API Level 28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148443/can-not-find-canvas-variables-in-api-level-28)

but when using the canvas.saveLayer(), it's not support for APIs under 21.

I get this error:

```
Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.graphics.Canvas#saveLayer
```

What should I do if I need support for API 19 and above?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, please see edit. Thanks!

Comment: There's [other overrides of `saveLayer()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#saveLayer(android.graphics.RectF,%2520android.graphics.Paint,%2520int)) available from API 1.

Comment: you can use canvas.save();